# Are these cron expression valid?

Tags: cron

I'm trying to learn the cron expression, but I'm pretty confused by few corner cases.
I've tried to test them on few online validator and even tried python-crontab module, but they gave the different result which make me more confused. 
Would someone explain the following cron expressions? Or any good way to validate a cron expression?

Online validator I tried:

1. http://cron.schlitt.info/
2. http://cronchecker.net/
3. http://www.cronmaker.com/

the cron expressions need explanation,

```
59-5/5 * *   *   *
1/2    * *   *   *
0      0 1/2 *   *
0      0 *   6/2 *
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say no, these cron expressions are not valid.

You shouldn't use them because you are not sure of what they do. I've tried that one `1/2 * * * * command` and it works but not as I thank. I thought it will work as `1 * * * * command` and it worked as `1-59/2 * * * * command`.

Perhaps some of these works but I repeat you shouldn't use them. The crontab manpage is clear enough to use range and step values in a good way :

```
 Ranges of numbers are allowed.  Ranges are two numbers separated with a
 hyphen.  The specified range is inclusive.  For example, 8-11 for an ``hours''
 entry specifies execution at hours 8, 9, 10 and 11.

 Lists are allowed.  A list is a set of numbers (or ranges) separated by com-
 mas.  Examples: ``1,2,5,9'', ``0-4,8-12''.

 Step values can be used in conjunction with ranges.  Following a range with
 ``/<number>'' specifies skips of the number's value through the range.  For
 example, ``0-23/2'' can be used in the hours field to specify command execu-
 tion every other hour (the alternative in the V7 standard is
 ``0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22'').  Steps are also permitted after an aster-
 isk, so if you want to say ``every two hours'', just use ``*/2''.
```

So when you use ranges, you have to specified two numbers separated with a hyphen. The range have to be like `first-last` so if you wanna do `50-15`, use comma and prefer `50-59,0-15`

If you want to use step values, they have to follow a range.

Don't make it harder than it is. It will be easier for guys who will have to read your work.